# Convert RFC3339? string to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, formatting, nsdate, rfc3339

I am trying to convert a string that looks like this (not sure if that fully correct RFC3339 format):

```
2014-07-07T16:11:02.085Z
```

To an NSDate. I've looked around and have tried multiple formats and am using code from Apple on converting around. Here is the formats I've been trying:

```
@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sss'Z'" //apples
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'999Z'"
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'"
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

How I'm going about it:

```
NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

// Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.
NSDate *date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-07-07T16:11:02.085Z"];

NSLog(@"date: = %@", date);

NSString *userVisibleDateTimeString;
if (date != nil) {
    // Convert the date object to a user-visible date string.
    NSDateFormatter *userVisibleDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    assert(userVisibleDateFormatter != nil);

    [userVisibleDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [userVisibleDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    userVisibleDateTimeString = [userVisibleDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}

NSLog(@"userVisibleDateTimeString = '%@'", userVisibleDateTimeString);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third try is almost correct. The date format should be

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

with capital "S" for "fractional seconds".